# Sobreescribir un archivo Excel con Java y Apache POI

Tags: java, excel

Muy buenas.

Tengo creado un aplicativo que recibe una fecha y escribe un archivo excel con información necesaria para llenar datos en una tabla dinámica en excel. La clase hasta el momento crea el archivo sin ningún problema, pero, desearía saber si puedo hacer que, en vez de crear un documento nuevo, vaya y sobreescriba uno existente con una tabla dinámica y formulas ya creadas, que solamente sobreescriba una Hoja llamada "BASE" (Que es la que contiene los datos para llenar la tabla dinámica) y no lo sobreescriba por completo dejando solamente la Hoja que crea y ya.

Este es el código que tengo para la creación del libro:

```
    public class EscribirExcel {
Calendar calendario = new GregorianCalendar();
String horaNueva = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
String fechaNueva = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
String d = String.valueOf(calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
String M = String.valueOf(calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
String y = String.valueOf(calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR));
String s = horaNueva.substring(6, 8);
String m = horaNueva.substring(3, 5);
String H = horaNueva.substring(0, 2);
String ruta = "Informes_Nomina/ReporteNomina.xlsx";
File archivoXLS = new File(ruta);
XSSFWorkbook libro =  new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet hoja = libro.createSheet("BASE");
XSSFRow fila;
XSSFCell celda;
int f = 1;
int c = 1;
int t = 1;
int max = 1;
public void crearArchivo(ResultSet rs) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException{
    String [] arrEncabezados = {"EMPLEADO",
                                "NOMBRE_EMPLEADO",
                                "LAPSO",
                                "CO_DE_MOVIMIENTO",
                                "NOMBRE_CENTROCOSTO",
                                "SALARIO",
                                "SUB_TRANSPORTE",
                                "H.E",
                                "OTROS",
                                "I.P",
                                "TOTAL",
                                "EMPRESA",
                                "003",
                                "004",
                                "008",
                                "009",
                                "010",
                                "011",
                                "015",
                                "018",
                                "051",
                                "052",
                                "053",
                                "055",
                                "660",
                                "750",
                                "850",
                                "860",
                                "EMPRESA"};
    FileOutputStream archivo = new FileOutputStream(archivoXLS);
    fila = hoja.createRow(0);
    for(int x = 0; x < arrEncabezados.length; x++){
        celda = fila.createCell(x);
        celda.setCellValue(arrEncabezados[x]);
    }

    if(rs.next()){
        while(rs.next()){
        fila = hoja.createRow(f);
            for(c = 1; c <= arrEncabezados.length; c++){
                celda = fila.createCell(c-1);
                celda.setCellValue(rs.getString(c));
            }  
        f++;
        }
        libro.write(archivo);
        archivo.close();
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(archivoXLS);
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Esta consulta no trae ninguna información");
        return;
    }


}
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

te falta obtener la ultima fila que tiene escrita el archivo, esta la puedes obtener mediante el siguiente metodo:

```
sheet.getLastRowNum()
```

te dejo  un link de un ejemplo y la documentación oficial:

[Link Ejemplo](http://www.codejava.net/coding/java-example-to-update-existing-excel-files-using-apache-poi)

[Documentación oficial](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#Reading+or+modifying+an+existing+file)

Comment: Como tal a lo que quiero llegar es tener ya un Excel con una Hoja llamada "BASE" y otras hojas con formulas ya predeterminadas que se actualizaran con la información que este en BASE. Sí obtengo la hoja que deseo modificar al momento que yo sobreescriba, ¿esto no me afectará las demás hojas?